# Анимированная маска для показа изображения (android)

Tags: android, анимация, glide, vector-drawable

Мне нужно показать часть изображения в виде определенной маски, которая постоянно изменяется. Для загрузки изображения использую Glide. Преобразовал изображение под нужную форму с помощью ответа на вопрос, который обсуждался тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966272/android-mask-bitmap-on-canvas-gen-a-black-space/26031133#26031133

Не понимаю что можно делать дальше.
Заходил с другой стороны и сделал сначала анимацию через AnimatedVectorDrawable. Через векторные изображения смог добиться анимации движения маски, но как наложить на изображение, скачанное с сети, не могу понять.

Пытался сделать через MotionScene, но там, как я понял, нельзя задавать какие-то сложные фигуры, под которые можно подстроить view. Находил пример только с кругом и квадратом.

Хочу понять в какую сторону мне лучше смотреть в этом вопросе. В Glide не нашел ничего подходящего. Может есть какие-то подходящие библиотеки, сам искал, не нашел.

Вот пример одного состояния маски, под которую хочу подогнать изображение:
[image: маска]